# kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead at path: $

Tags: android, json

I'm calling https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/?q=jazz+history which gives a response of the form:

```json
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 2921,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "J9G50L3c14QC",
      "etag": "PY+UHRpZHsM",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/J9G50L3c14QC",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "The History of Jazz",
        "authors": [
          "Ted Gioia"
        ],
        "publisher": "Oxford University Press",
        "publishedDate": "2011-05-09",
        "description": "Ted Gioia's History of Jazz has been universally hailed as a classic--acclaimed by jazz critics and fans around the world. Now Gioia brings his magnificent work completely up-to-date, drawing on the latest research and revisiting virtually every aspect of the music, past and present. Gioia tells the story of jazz as it had never been told before, in a book that brilliantly portrays the legendary jazz players, the breakthrough styles, and the world in which it evolved. Here are the giants of jazz and the great moments of jazz history--Jelly Roll Morton, Louis Armstrong, Duke Ellington at the Cotton Club, cool jazz greats such as Gerry Mulligan, Stan Getz, and Lester Young, Charlie Parker and Dizzy Gillespie's advocacy of modern jazz in the 1940s, Miles Davis's 1955 performance at the Newport Jazz Festival, Ornette Coleman's experiments with atonality, Pat Metheny's visionary extension of jazz-rock fusion, the contemporary sounds of Wynton Marsalis, and the post-modernists of the current day. Gioia provides the reader with lively portraits of these and many other great musicians, intertwined with vibrant commentary on the music they created. He also evokes the many worlds of jazz, taking the reader to the swamp lands of the Mississippi Delta, the bawdy houses of New Orleans, the rent parties of Harlem, the speakeasies of Chicago during the Jazz Age, the after hours spots of corrupt Kansas city, the Cotton Club, the Savoy, and the other locales where the history of jazz was made. And as he traces the spread of this protean form, Gioia provides much insight into the social context in which the music was born.",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "0199831874"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9780199831876"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "pageCount": 452,
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "categories": [
          "Music"
        ],
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": true,
        "contentVersion": "0.11.6.0.preview.3",
        "panelizationSummary": {
          "containsEpubBubbles": false,
          "containsImageBubbles": false
        },
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=J9G50L3c14QC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=J9G50L3c14QC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.ie/books?id=J9G50L3c14QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=jazz+history&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=J9G50L3c14QC&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=J9G50L3c14QC"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "saleability": "FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": true,
        "listPrice": {
          "amount": 11.87,
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
          "amount": 8.07,
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "buyLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=J9G50L3c14QC&rdid=book-J9G50L3c14QC&rdot=1&source=gbs_api",
        "offers": [
          {
            "finskyOfferType": 1,
            "listPrice": {
              "amountInMicros": 11870000,
              "currencyCode": "EUR"
            },
            "retailPrice": {
              "amountInMicros": 8070000,
              "currencyCode": "EUR"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-epub.acsm?id=J9G50L3c14QC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-pdf.acsm?id=J9G50L3c14QC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=J9G50L3c14QC&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      },
      "searchInfo": {
        "textSnippet": "Here are the giants of jazz and the great moments of jazz history--Jelly Roll Morton, Louis Armstrong, Duke Ellington at the Cotton Club, cool jazz greats such as Gerry Mulligan, Stan Getz, and Lester Young, Charlie Parker and Dizzy ..."
      }
    },
[...]
{
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "OqfrqNncZXAC",
      "etag": "48K6FFTp+SQ",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/OqfrqNncZXAC",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "Historical Dictionary of Jazz",
        "authors": [
          "John S. Davis"
        ],
        "publisher": "Scarecrow Press",
        "publishedDate": "2012-09-13",
        "description": "The Historical Dictionary of Jazz covers the history of Jazz through a chronology, an introductory essay, and an extensive bibliography. The dictionary section has over 1,500 cross-referenced entries on significant jazz performers, band leaders, bands, venues, record labels, recordings, and the different styles of jazz. This book is an excellent access point for students, researchers, and anyone seeking a broader understanding of the history of jazz and the connections within the genre.",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9780810878983"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "0810878984"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "pageCount": 470,
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "categories": [
          "Music"
        ],
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "2.3.3.0.preview.3",
        "panelizationSummary": {
          "containsEpubBubbles": false,
          "containsImageBubbles": false
        },
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.ie/books?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=jazz+history&hl=&cd=10&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=OqfrqNncZXAC"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "saleability": "FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": true,
        "listPrice": {
          "amount": 119,
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
          "amount": 92.86,
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        },
        "buyLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&rdid=book-OqfrqNncZXAC&rdot=1&source=gbs_api",
        "offers": [
          {
            "finskyOfferType": 1,
            "listPrice": {
              "amountInMicros": 119000000,
              "currencyCode": "EUR"
            },
            "retailPrice": {
              "amountInMicros": 92860000,
              "currencyCode": "EUR"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/Historical_Dictionary_of_Jazz-sample-epub.acsm?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/Historical_Dictionary_of_Jazz-sample-pdf.acsm?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=OqfrqNncZXAC&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      },
      "searchInfo": {
        "textSnippet": "This book is an excellent access point for students, researchers, and anyone seeking a broader understanding of the history of jazz and the connections within the genre."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

though, I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.bookshelf, PID: 7875
                                                                                                    kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead at path: $
                                                                                                    JSON input: .....",
                                                                                                            "quoteSharingAllowed": false
                                                                                                          }
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                      ]
                                                                                                    }
```

#### BookshelfApiService.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface BookshelfApiService {
    @GET("?q=jazz+history")
    suspend fun getBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>

    @GET("{volume_id}")
    suspend fun getVolume(@Path("id") id: String): BookshelfVolume
}
```

#### BookshelfBook.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class BookshelfBook(
    val id: String
)
```

#### BookshelfVolume.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class BookshelfVolume(
    val imageLinks: Map<String, String>
)
```

#### BookshelfRepository.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.data

import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfApiService
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfBook
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfVolume

interface BookshelfRepository {
    suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>
    suspend fun getBookshelfVolume(id: String): BookshelfVolume
}

class NetworkBookshelfRepository(
    private val bookshelfApiService: BookshelfApiService
) : BookshelfRepository {
    override suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook> =
        bookshelfApiService.getBooks()

    override suspend fun getBookshelfVolume(id: String): BookshelfVolume =
        bookshelfApiService.getVolume(id)
}
```

#### BookshelfViewModel.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.ui.model

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.Companion.APPLICATION_KEY
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.initializer
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.viewModelFactory
import com.example.bookshelf.BookshelfApplication
import com.example.bookshelf.data.BookshelfRepository
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfVolume
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.IOException

sealed interface BookshelfUiState {
    data class Success(val volumes: List<BookshelfVolume>): BookshelfUiState
    object Loading: BookshelfUiState
    object Error: BookshelfUiState
}

class BookshelfViewModel(
    private val bookshelfRepository: BookshelfRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var bookshelfUiState: BookshelfUiState by mutableStateOf(BookshelfUiState.Loading)
        private set

    init {
        getBookshelfVolumes()
    }

    fun getBookshelfVolumes() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookshelfUiState = try {
                val books = bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfBooks().map { it.id }
                val volumes = books.map { id ->
                    bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfVolume(id)
                }
                BookshelfUiState.Success(volumes)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                BookshelfUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as BookshelfApplication)
                val bookshelfRepository = application.container.bookshelfRepository
                BookshelfViewModel(bookshelfRepository = bookshelfRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### AppContainer.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.data

import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfApiService
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.asConverterFactory
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import retrofit2.Retrofit

interface AppContainer {
    val bookshelfRepository: BookshelfRepository
}

class DefaultAppContainer : AppContainer {

    private val baseUrl =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/"

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build()

    private val retrofitService: BookshelfApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(BookshelfApiService::class.java)
    }

    override val bookshelfRepository: BookshelfRepository by lazy {
        NetworkBookshelfRepository(retrofitService)
    }
}
```

---

#### What I've tried

Loading the response from Google API into Python3 using `json` library works. It seems the Json module in Android Studio is the one failing.

How can I debug this better?

Is it the problem really with the data Google API is serving? I'm hoping to be wrong and just have something missing on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function getBooks is returning List<BookshelfBook> which is wrong.
Please follow the steps below:

1. Correct your return type of the function.

> ```
> @GET("?q=jazz+history")
> suspend fun getBooks(): BooksResponse
> ```

2. Correct the data classes accordingly.

> ```
> data class BooksResponse (
>    val kind: String,
>    val totalItems: Int,
>    val items: List<Book>  
>  )
> ```

> ```
> data class Book (
>    val kind: String,
>    val id: String,
>    val etag: String,
>    val selfLink: String
>  )
> ```

3. I've added only few keys for example. You can add the required keys for parsing.

The problem is that the response is returning an object but you are expecting a list which is throwing an error while parsing the response.